# C++ code to find all ip address in a file

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I need to write a program to scan a text file and retrieve all ip addresses (of the format 256.256.256.256) in the file.

Comment: 256 is not a valid octet, by the way.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs. Regular expression it is.. 
Also planning on using perl, guess will make it much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a BNF using [Boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/spirit/classic/index.html) or create a regular expression to find the IP addresses using [Boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try using regular expressions? You could read the file in, scanning it line by line maybe, and then use a regular expression on the line to extract the IP addresses.

If the file contains only IP addresses and no other text, it might be easier to use `scanf`, with `"%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu"` as the format string.

Answer (score 1):

This Regular Expression will do the trick:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Modify this code for your specific needs:

```
using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;
void doTheMatch( String^ inputString, String^ filter )
{
    Console::WriteLine( "original string:  {0}", inputString );
    Console::WriteLine( "attempt to match: {0}", filter );

    Regex^ regex = gcnew Regex( filter );
    Match^ match = regex->Match( inputString );

    if ( ! match->Success )
    {
        Console::WriteLine( 
            "Sorry, no match of {0} in {1}", filter, inputString );
        return;
    }

    for ( ; match->Success; match = match->NextMatch() )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( 
            "The characters {0} match beginning at position {1}",  
            match->ToString(), match->Index );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does System::Text::RegularExpressions come from?

Comment: isn't this a question about C++ not c# ?? 
I could contribute an answer in Perl too after all ...

Comment: I think this is managed C++ not C#. Either way it's hard to know what the author wanted. This seems like it should help though.

Comment: I was assuming this was managed C++, since it was not specified

Answer (score 0):

Does it really have to be C++? Regular expressions and `grep` are your friends!

Comment: Perhaps he wants to make connections to the IP addresses that he is reading in.